# Oracle Apex Submit and Open modal in the same time

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I want to make a double action on submit.

In this moment I have  one form and I need to make two actions in the same time on submit. Below it's the first action to create n number of tabs and n number of record lines inside each tab. Now I'm trying keep this functionality which works and also open a modal window from another page and resubmit the page every time i click Submit button.

```
BEGIN
    IF (:P2_CREATE_TABS != 0 OR :P2_CREATE_TABS != NULL) AND :P2_CREATE_TABS <= 5 THEN
        htp.p ('<nav><div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">');
        FOR k IN 1..:P2_CREATE_TABS
        LOOP
            IF k = 1 THEN
                htp.p ('<a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-'||k||'-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-'||k||'" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-'||k||'" aria-selected="true">Document '||k||'</a>');
            ELSE
                htp.p ('<a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-'||k||'-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-'||k||'" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-'||k||'" aria-selected="false">Document '||k||'</a>');
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
        htp.p('</div></nav><div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">');
        FOR l IN 1..:P2_CREATE_TABS
        LOOP
            IF l = 1 THEN
                htp.p ('<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-'||l||'" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-'||l||'-tab">');
                    IF (:P2_LINES != 0 OR :P2_LINES != NULL) AND :P2_LINES < 20 THEN
                       htp.p ('<div class="row"><div class"col-md-6"  style="margin-left: 17em;"><table class="table">');
                       FOR i IN 1..:P2_LINES
                       LOOP
                           IF MOD(i,2) != 0 THEN
                               htp.p ('<thead><tr><th scope="col"> </th><th scope="col">Name</th><th scope="col">Type</th><th scope="col">Width</th><tbody>');
                               htp.p ('<tr><th scope="row">'|| i ||'</th><td>');
                               htp.p ( APEX_ITEM.HIDDEN(
                                   p_idx => 1,
                                   p_item_label => 'ID') );
                               htp.p ( APEX_ITEM.TEXT(
                                   p_idx => 2, 
                                   p_item_label => 'Name',
                                   p_attributes => 'class="form-control"'));
                               htp.p ('</td><td>');
                               htp.p ( APEX_ITEM.SELECT_LIST(
                                   p_idx           =>   3,
                                   p_list_values   =>   'Numeric;20',
                                   p_show_null     =>   'YES',
                                   p_null_value    =>   '10',
                                   p_null_text     =>   'Alphnumeric',
                                   p_item_label => 'Type',
                                   p_attributes => 'class="form-control"') );
                               htp.p ('</td><td>');
                               htp.p ( APEX_ITEM.TEXT(
                                   p_idx => 3, 
                                   p_item_label => 'Width',
                                   p_attributes => 'class="form-control"') );
                               htp.p ('</td></tr>');
                           END IF;
                        END LOOP;
                        htp.p ('</tbody></table></div><div class"col-md-6" style="margin-left: 17em;"><table class="table">');
                        FOR j IN 2..:P2_LINES
                        LOOP
                            IF MOD(j,2) = 0 THEN
                                htp.p ('<thead><tr><th scope="col"> </th><th scope="col">Name</th><th scope="col">Type</th><th scope="col">Width</th><tbody>');
                                htp.p ('<tr><th scope="row">'|| j ||'</th><td>');
                                htp.p ( APEX_ITEM.HIDDEN(
                                    p_idx => 1,
                                    p_item_label => 'ID') );
                                htp.p ( APEX_ITEM.TEXT(
                                    p_idx => 2, 
                                    p_item_label => 'Name',
                                    p_attributes => 'class="form-control"'));
                                htp.p ('</td><td>');
                                htp.p ( APEX_ITEM.SELECT_LIST(
                                   p_idx           =>   3,
                                   p_list_values   =>   'Numeric;20',
                                   p_show_null     =>   'YES',
                                   p_null_value    =>   '10',
                                   p_null_text     =>   'Alphnumeric',
                                   p_item_label => 'Type',
                                   p_attributes => 'class="form-control"') );
                                htp.p ('</td><td>');
                                htp.p ( APEX_ITEM.TEXT(
                                    p_idx => 3, 
                                    p_item_label => 'Width',
                                    p_attributes => 'class="form-control"') );
                                htp.p ('</td></tr>');
                            END IF;
                        END LOOP;
                        htp.p ('</tbody></table></div></div>');  
                    END IF;       
                htp.p ('</div>');
            END IF;
                htp.p ('<div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-'||l||'" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-'||l||'-tab">');
                    IF (:P2_LINES != 0 OR :P2_LINES != NULL) AND :P2_LINES < 20 THEN
                       htp.p ('<div class="row"><div class"col-md-6"  style="margin-left: 17em;"><table class="table">');
                       FOR i IN 1..:P2_LINES
                       LOOP
                           IF MOD(i,2) != 0 THEN
                               htp.p ('<thead><tr><th scope="col"> </th><th scope="col">Name</th><th scope="col">Type</th><th scope="col">Width</th><tbody>');
                               htp.p ('<tr><th scope="row">'|| i ||'</th><td>');
                               htp.p ( APEX_ITEM.HIDDEN(
                                   p_idx => 1,
                                   p_item_label => 'ID') );
                               htp.p ( APEX_ITEM.TEXT(
                                   p_idx => 2, 
                                   p_item_label => 'Name',
                                   p_attributes => 'class="form-control"'));
                               htp.p ('</td><td>');
                               htp.p ( APEX_ITEM.SELECT_LIST(
                                   p_idx           =>   3,
                                   p_list_values   =>   'Numeric;20',
                                   p_show_null     =>   'YES',
                                   p_null_value    =>   '10',
                                   p_null_text     =>   'Alphnumeric',
                                   p_item_label => 'Type',
                                   p_attributes => 'class="form-control"') );
                               htp.p ('</td><td>');
                               htp.p ( APEX_ITEM.TEXT(
                                   p_idx => 3, 
                                   p_item_label => 'Width',
                                   p_attributes => 'class="form-control"') );
                               htp.p ('</td></tr>');
                           END IF;
                        END LOOP;
                        htp.p ('</tbody></table></div><div class"col-md-6" style="margin-left: 17em;"><table class="table">');
                        FOR j IN 2..:P2_LINES
                        LOOP
                            IF MOD(j,2) = 0 THEN
                                htp.p ('<thead><tr><th scope="col"> </th><th scope="col">Name</th><th scope="col">Type</th><th scope="col">Width</th><tbody>');
                                htp.p ('<tr><th scope="row">'|| j ||'</th><td>');
                                htp.p ( APEX_ITEM.HIDDEN(
                                    p_idx => 1,
                                    p_item_label => 'ID') );
                                htp.p ( APEX_ITEM.TEXT(
                                    p_idx => 2, 
                                    p_item_label => 'Name',
                                    p_attributes => 'class="form-control"'));
                                htp.p ('</td><td>');
                                htp.p ( APEX_ITEM.SELECT_LIST(
                                   p_idx           =>   3,
                                   p_list_values   =>   'Numeric;20',
                                   p_show_null     =>   'YES',
                                   p_null_value    =>   '10',
                                   p_null_text     =>   'Alphnumeric',
                                   p_item_label => 'Type',
                                   p_attributes => 'class="form-control"') );
                                htp.p ('</td><td>');
                                htp.p ( APEX_ITEM.TEXT(
                                    p_idx => 3, 
                                    p_item_label => 'Width',
                                    p_attributes => 'class="form-control"') );
                                htp.p ('</td></tr>');
                            END IF;
                        END LOOP;
                        htp.p ('</tbody></table></div></div>');  
                    END IF;       
                htp.p ('</div>');
        END LOOP;
        htp.p('</div>');
    END IF;
END;
```

I have created one Hidden Item and linked it to one Computation After Submit with PL/SQL Function Body, code below:

```
BEGIN
    IF :P2_CUST_NAME != '' AND :P2_ORG_NUM != NULL AND :P2_CONTACT_NUM != NULL AND :P2_EMAIL != '' THEN
        RETURN 'Y';
    END IF;
END;
```

Created a Branch After processing with server-side condition `When Button Pressed = MY_BUTTON` and Behavior set to desired page.

Next step I've created a Dynamic Action with `Event=Dialogue Closed`, `Selection Type=Region` and for the region I chose the region where i have the Submit Button.

In this moment, if i have something in first two input fields that creates Tabs and Fields inside tabs will create them dynamically automatically without any submit because i didn't force clear cache. If i change values and input the rest of fields, le wild modal window appears but the page it's not submitted and data it's not fetched again from fields to build other structure.

I think i'm close and i can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Submitting the page causes your page to reload (unless you branch to a different one), so your old page no longer exists. Thus, I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have two different forms on the same page with the same submit button . What i'm trying to do is to submit both forms in the same time. Works only for one of them because it's not submitting anymore and just opens my modal window but i still need to update the other form .

Comment: I'm new to Oracle Apex and PL/SQL, i'm trying to learn and maybe my approach it's not correct, please correct me if i'm wrong. Mainly what i'm trying to do it's keep the first functionality and create dynamically n number of tabs and n numbers of rows inside each tab plus the new functionality to open a popup window dynamically. If you can suggest some websites also it would be great and really helps, didn't found anything looking after my keywords.

Comment: Do conditions like `:P2_ORG_NUM != NULL` really work for you as expected? I thought the normal way of checking if a value is a null was using the `IS NULL` predicate, but I never worked with PL/SQL so maybe it supports both ways.

Comment: Andriy is right, you can't test for NULL like that. See here: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=79f187578f00760e771171d4b8667b90

Comment: I switched from C# to Oracle and i'm really new. This project helps me to understand more and i want to thank Andriy and Jack. I know that's not how i suppose to do it. They work but i will change them. Still trying to learn new things.

Comment: "They work but i will change them": for example `:P2_ORG_NUM != NULL` always evaluates to `NULL` whatever `P2_ORG_NUM` is.

Comment: Besides the NULL issue, the construction `(x != 0 OR x != c)` doesn't seem good either. Perhaps it's a pattern used in C# but won't be useful in SQL.

Comment: The `:P2_CUST_NAME != ''` is not good either, because in Oracle `''` and `NULL` are the same thing so the expression means  `:P2_CUST_NAME != NULL` which always resolves to NULL/UNKNOWN.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ , what did you said it's true but i don't understand something . You said "the construction (x != 0 OR x != c) doesn't seem good either." , I haven't used something like this. Are you referring to "(:P2_LINES != 0 OR :P2_LINES IS NOT NULL)", you can noticed i'we changed != null but in the first case `:P2_LINES != 0` here i'm checking field value that it's different than 0, i don't know any other approach. Please tell me if this is what you referred to.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to `IF (:P2_CREATE_TABS != 0 OR :P2_CREATE_TABS != NULL)` and `IF (:P2_LINES != 0 OR :P2_LINES != NULL)` I mean that if you use it with non-null comparisons, eg. `IF (x != 0 OR x != 5)` then it's useless in C# because it's always true, or equivalent to `(x IS NOT NULL)` in SQL.

Comment: I can imagine `IF (x != 0 **AND** x != 5)` to be useful.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ yes but when i wrote x =! 0 i’m saying that x is not 0 , i’m not saying x is not null , i want to ensure that user it’s not using value 0 . In this case is correct ?

Comment: That is fine, sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making a **Branch After Process** that will run when **Submit Button** is clicked, then inside its set up, at the lower part, you can see '**Advanced**' where you can set a **Request**. You can set/name any request, for example set it as, '**OPEN_MODAL**'.

Then on the redirected page(other page or same page) after submit, make a dynamic action on page load that will open the modal(javascript or pl sql) then set its condition to **REQUEST = VALUE** and set value as '**OPEN_MODAL**'

this will open the modal on the redirected page after submitting the main page.

hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I used branches as you said and read online more about them and this helped .